# When is html languagechange event fired in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, localization, dom-events

I am trying to add localization in a simple web app.
There is a `languagechange` event as per [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/languagechange_event).

My questions is:

- when is this event actually fired?

Here is what I tried.

- page html tag has lang attribute `<html lang='ar-SA'>`
- user can use some dropdown to switch to another language.
- the dropdown, changes the lang attribute on html tag to the desired lang

I was hoping that changing lang attribute on root html tag will fire the `languagechange` event, which in turn I can use to load the content in new lang, but it does not.

Did I miss something obvious here?

Comment: It fires when the user changes their preferred language in the browser preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The languagechange event is fired at the global scope object when the user's preferred language changes.

```
window.onlanguagechange = function(event) {
  console.log('languagechange event detected!');
};
```

Check your Browser compatibility

Answer (score -1):

This will help you, In this code, I'm accessing the browser HTML lang attribute continuously and taking on lang attribute value change.

```js
let currentLanguage = document.querySelector('[lang]').attributes.lang.value.toString();
setInterval(function () {
    let Language = document.querySelector('[lang]').attributes.lang.value.toString();
    if (currentLanguage != Language) {
        let LanguageName = new Intl.DisplayNames(["en"], { type: 'language' });
        console.log('Translated Language :', LanguageName.of(Language));
        currentLanguage = Language;
    } clearInterval();
},);
```

Comment: You will need to add yout HTML as well, without that your code does not execute properly.